# Setting multiples out of order variables with pattern

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a file in the following format (note that some lines have the variables inverted, in the example, line 3):

```
var1: valueA var2: valueB
var1: valueC var2: valueD
var2: valueF var1: valueE
var1: valueG var2: valueH
```

And I'm trying to use awk to print an output in the format (var1|var2):

```
valueA|valueB
valueC|valueD
valueE|valueF
valueG|valueH
```

I've tried to split and set the value based on patterns like this:

```
$ awk -v OFS='|' '{split($0,a," ")} /^var1:/{var1=a[2]} /^var2:/{var2=a[2]} {print var1, var2}' test.txt
valueA|
valueC|
valueC|valueF
valueG|valueF
```

But all tries that I did ending with missing results or duplicated values.
Is there any way to set and print the variables based on the variables names (patterns)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you have name=value pairs like you do I find it best to first create an array of those pairings (`f[]` below) and then you can just access the value(s) by their name(s), e.g.:

```
$ awk -F'[: ]+' -v OFS='|' '{for (i=1;i<NF;i+=2) f[$i]=$(i+1); print f["var1"], f["var2"]}' file
valueA|valueB
valueC|valueD
valueE|valueF
valueG|valueH
```

Comment: Worked great! Can you explain how `f[$i]=$(i+1)` works? It creates an array and appends the values based on the separator `:`?

Comment: When i is 1 i+1 is 2 so when i is 1 $i is `var1` and $(i+1) is `valueA`. So you get an array populated as `f["var1"] = "valueA"`, etc. as you go through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* a better answer, but it's fun:

```
grep -oP '\w+:\s+(.*?)(?=\s+\w+:|$)' file |
  sort --stable -t: -k1,1 | 
  cut -d" " -f2- | 
  pr -2T -s"|"
```

Answer (score 0):

could you please try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/var1: [^ ]*/){
   val=substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)
   match($0,/var2: [^ ]*/)
   print val"|"substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)
}'  Input_file
```

OR(since first code will have a limitation it will look for `val1` string should be present as well as string `val2` too, so to avoid that one could try):

```
awk '
match($0,/var1: [^ ]*/){
   val=substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)
}
match($0,/var2: [^ ]*/){
   print val"|"substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)
}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
valueA|valueB
valueC|valueD
valueE|valueF
valueG|valueH
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
perl -lne ' %kv=/(var\S+)\s+(\S+)/g; for(sort keys %kv) 
            { printf("%s%s",$s,$kv{$_}); $s="|"  } print "";$s="" ' file
```

with your given inputs

```
$ cat ajk.txt
var1: valueA var2: valueB
var1: valueC var2: valueD
var2: valueF var1: valueE
var1: valueG var2: valueH

$ perl -lne ' %kv=/(var\S+)\s+(\S+)/g; for(sort keys %kv) 
      { printf("%s%s",$s,$kv{$_}); $s="|"  } print "";$s="" ' ajk.txt
valueA|valueB
valueC|valueD
valueE|valueF
valueG|valueH

$
```